# Systematic Spacing between Org Mode Objects

Tags: org-mode

When I write org mode files it's difficult to keep the right number of blank lines between different org mode objects like source blocks, text blocks, headings, and tables. There exists `org-blank-before-new-entry` which helps with this a little bit, but it only accepts two kinds of objects a heading or a plain list item.

Too often I see this line highlighting at the end oforg mode headings that have one space or less:
[image: fold is highlighted at the end]

I also see unusual folding images sometimes. Below under `#+end-src` there is an unusual fold.
[image: bad folding]

When I expand it there's nothing there except for whitespace.

It is cumbersome to be fixing these myself whenever I add forget to add blank lines or add to many.

Is something that exists to format an org file to have the proper spacing between org objects?